# Ajax doesn't return succes or error but is done and complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to make an ajax request which doesn't call either success or error on completion and still gives back a done and complete status?

```
function execute_given_operation(operation, operation_data, succes_function, error_function, done_function) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "/framework/ope/" + operation,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: operation_data,
        succes: function (data) {
            succes_function;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            error_function(data);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }

    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('x', response);

    });
}

function contact_accomplish() {

$("#load_assign_gif").css("display", "block");

execute_given_operation("LEAD_INBOX_MENU_KONTAKT_WYKONANY","{\"LEADYLEADID\":" + window.object.LEADID + " }\n",
    function(){console.log("jupi");},
    function(){console.log("nope");},
    function(){});
}
```

So when I call the function contact_accomplish, I have something like this:
 complete return a 200 status, and the done function returns JSON data which means operation "LEAD_INBOX_MENU_KONTAKT_WYKONANY" was ended successfully:

```
    {
  "step2of3": [
    {
      "GetStatusInfoResult": {
        "ImportDate": "2016-03-31T14:10:25",
        "OpenDate": "2016-04-05T15:41:49",
        "TargetContactDate": "2016-01-29T19:35:49",
        "StatusName": "Open Lead",
        "AssignedToDealer": true,
        "TargetOpenDate": "2016-01-29T19:05:49",
        "StatusCode": "OPEN",
        "CloseDate": null,
        "TargetCloseDate": "2016-03-29T18:35:49",
        "StatusDescription": "",
        "ReminderCloseDate": null,
        "AllocationDate": "2016-01-29T18:35:49",
        "ReallocationDate": null,
        "LeadID": 3739260943,
        "ContactDate": "2016-04-06T13:17:19"
      }
    }
  ],
  "step1of3": {
    "UpdateLeadContactedResponse": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  "step3of3": [
    "OK"
  ]
}
```

So if it's returning data, why is it not calling my 'success' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First correct the key of ajax success. You used `succes`. You have to replace with `success`. and use success callback as `succes_function();`. You just specified `succes_function;`.

Comment: Thanks i don't see this mistake :)